Using stripe services to create an in-app currency
I have a question about whether making an in-app currency using the stripe payments & stripe connected accounts would be right and compliant.
This currency (let's call it coin) will have the following capabilities:

Buy coins with real money using stripe payment
Buy digital products inside the app
Send coins to other users inside the app
Convert coins to real money & withdraw to a connected account

In teory is possible to implement this in the thechincal part, but I do not know about the legal part.
I found out that this is called a "convertible virtual currency", that have legal requirements but looks like stripe handle most of these requirements, so maybe?
Someone that had made a system like that can give me a light?
Thank you in advance!

The only part about this that doesn't seem feasible to me is converting in-app currency into real money, I think this would require certain security standards to be met to protect user's in-app currency from being stolen and transferred. It would probably be better to use a crypto currency which can already be traded for real money, rather than developing something from scratch. But, I'm not a lawyer.

I'd recommend reaching out to Stripe's support team instead to discuss your exact business model and what they can and can't support. StackOverflow can't really speak to their policies.
